# Embedded SQLite database for Android App (Qt)

Tags: android, database, qt, sqlite, qt5

I got the following problem:
I'm developing a cross platform application (Linux/Android) and I'm stuck at deploying my SQLite database to Android - it works perfectly well for Linux.
I managed to add my db file to assets through the following code in my .pro file

```
deployment.files += rako.db

deployment.path = /assets

INSTALLS += deployment
```

Now in my DbManager C++ file where I handle my Database Connections I'm not able to get the SQLite database running :(

```
db_.setDatabaseName("assets:/rako.db");
```

Do I miss something?

Thanks guys,

Max

Answer (score 0):

> Do I miss something?

Actually, yes.
Assuming that your `assets` folder is under `android` folder you should add at your `pro` file next line:

```
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
```

All content fo `android` folder will be copied to `apk`.

Next thing is that `assests` on Android is read-only folder. So before use database, you should copy it from `assets` to another location.

Answer (score 0):

```
QFile dfile("assets:/db/database-last.db3");
if (dfile.exists())
{
    dfile.copy("./database-last.db3");
    QFile::setPermissions("./database-last.db3",QFile::WriteOwner |     QFile::ReadOwner);
 }
```

...

```
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
 db.setDatabaseName("./database-last.db3");
 db.open();
```

...

in .pro file

```
 deployment.files += database-last.db3
 deployment.path = /assets/db
 INSTALLS += deployment
```

It works on Android, but how to do same on iOS and Winphone?

Answer (score 0):

in dbmanager cpp file

```
QString path1 = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation);
QString path = path1 +"/Appfolder/rako.db";
if(QFile::copy("assets:/rako.db", path))
{
    qDebug() <<"db copied" << endl;
}
```

.pro file

```
android {
    QT += androidextras
    deployment.files += rako.db
    deployment.path = /assets
    INSTALLS += deployment
}
```

Comment: And here's the reason why this copying is necessary at all: the underlying SQLite3 library cannot understand the `assets:/` and qarc:/` schemes, it needs plain filesystem paths ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596863)).